# Django 2 - reverse for view not found

Tags: django, django-views

I know there are already a hundred of these, but I have one app that I made, that works, and a new one I'm trying to make, that doesn't work.

I can't redirect to my `'detail'` view from my create view. If I put a number into the address, it works, it is just the redirect that doesn't work. I've tried a couple of things to no avail. I'm sure it is something simple, I just can't see it.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
app_name = 'service'
urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.create_employee_profile,    
            name='create_employee_profile'),
        path('<int:pk>/', views.customer_employee_profile_detail,
            name='detail'),
]
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from service.forms import EmployeeNameForm

def create_employee_profile(request):

    if request.POST:
        name_form = EmployeeNameForm(request.POST)

        if name_form.is_valid():
            new_name_form = name_form.save()
            return redirect('service:detail', pk=new_name_form.pk)

        else:
            return render(request, 'service/create_or_update_profile.html',
                        {'name_form': name_form})

    else:
        name_form = EmployeeNameForm()
        return render(request, 'service/create_or_update_profile.html',
                        {'name_form': name_form})

def customer_employee_profile_detail(request, pk):
    name = get_object_or_404(CustomerEmployeeName, pk=pk)
    return render(request,
                    'service/customer_employee_profile_detail.html', 
                    {'name': name}
                )
```

I've tried both `'detail'` and `'service: detail'` as well. Error is:
`Reverse for 'detail' not found. 'detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <!--Content Header Bar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
            <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Name and Address</span>
        </nav>
        <div class="form-group">
            {% include 'service/name_form_template.html' %}
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: SteelBlue;">
            Save
        </button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

The included template holds the layout.

The reason I’m not using generic views is because these will views will eventually contain multiple forms. I’m trying to build it like legos, start small and add on.

Comment: show the html file for this view

Comment: What is the reason against using generic views?

Comment: You have `app_name = 'service'`, so `service:detail` is correct. How are you including `service/urls.py`?

Comment: @cezar Can you use multiple forms and models with generic views?

Comment: I'd say yes, if you tweak them, depending on the usecase. Probably I wouldn't do that. Why do you ask? The views in your example are very straight-forward and you could go with the class based views provided by Django.

Comment: @cezar Eventually I am going to add `PhoneNumber` and `Address` forms to this view, with the ability to have multiples of each with a `foreignKey` back to the `EmployeeName`. Maybe I missed it, but I haven't found where I can use multiple models on a `CreateView` or how to implement it.

Comment: I suggested generic views based on your code example. If you want to add related models, you could eventually use some kind of nested forms. However there is no reason to use class based views for the sake of classes. If you need finer adjustment go with function based views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcut function `redirect` can accept also a model object as a first argument. In that case it would call the `get_absolute_url` method of the model class. I'd recommend to go with this approach, as it would put the logic in the model class. That would result in the so called **fat models - thin controllers** pattern. In Django it would be rather **fat models - thin views**.

So, without knowing anything about your models, I'm assuming some details and propose this:

```
class CustomerEmployeeName(models.Model):
    # fields

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.urls import reverse
        return reverse('service:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

In your views you can change the line with the redirect to:

```
redirect(new_name_form)
```

This eventualy won't solve your problem immediately, as it is probably somewhere else, but it's in my opinion a better approach. The code is reusable and follows the DRY-principles.